# i have a problem to check wheather the input is string or number

Tags: c++, string, integer

trying to find out:
if the user enter a string or a number , but when trying to enter a number it just enter an inifiti loop , and just print "enter your name ",and i want if its a string after entering the loop , to just get out the loop.

```
#include <iostream>
#include<sstream>
#include<cmath>
#include<iomanip>
using namespace std;

 main()
{
  string name;

  cout<<"enter your name :";
  cin>>name;

  stringstream s;
  int x;
  s<<name;
  s>>x;
  while(x!=0)
  {
    cout<<"enter your name :";
    cin>>name;
    s<<name;
    s>>x;
    
  }


   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If a stream can't parse the wanted input to the variable, it will set an internal fail flag.

This flag can be checked by using the stream in a condition.

And the extraction operator returns a reference to the stream.

Put together you can do something like

```
while (s >> x)
{
    // String starts with a number...
    s.clear();  // Clear fail state flag
    // TODO: Ask for new input, set contents of s
}
```